# Upgrading from Magento 1.4.0.1 to 2.0.17

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, magento-1.4

My clients have a very old Magento store (1.4.0.1, from 2010) and they'd like to upgrade and use a theme that works with Magento CE 2.0.X.

I have installed a fresh Magento 2.0.17, with an empty database.

What would you recommend to bring the old site (1000 products, 3 stores/languages, 8 years of clients) to the new site?

I have been browsing the [Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) but it seems it doesn't support such an old version.

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest, you may try updating 1.4.0.1 to latest version in various steps like : upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6 then 1.6 to 1.7 then 1.7 to 1.8 then 1.8 to 1.9.3.4. once 1.9.3.4 you have then you can migrate to Magento 2 using migration tool.

Comment: First, you need to upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6 and then 1.6 to latest 1.9.X.Then you have to ugrade1.9 to 2..2..X version

Comment: I have read that it's wise not to skip version 1.4.2.0 and 1.5.1 so I may try going from 1.4.0.1 to those versions, then the rest of "key" versions https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/1-4-1-1-version-upgrade/td-p/14153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Migration Tool for Magento 2 is really helpful util. I am doing upgrade website from 1.5.9 to 2.1 in past and have tips & recomendations for you.

1. As answer Kumar: upgrate Magento 1.4 to 1.6.2 manually. You can replace core extensions and Magento will upgrade db schema after you open admin panel.
2. Prepare the list of extensions that aren't support now. You need them before use data migration tool for creating lists for ignoring or replace  attributes in products, orders, customers, etc.
3. After XML files with settings will be ready run data migration step by step and fix issues what is you see. Typicaly it's attributes from custom extension issues but sometimes is orphan entities may happening if you integrity of DB was broken. This is non critical. After any errors DB of target Magento 2 will be reverted.

Just fix issues what Data Migration Tool is told you and run it again. Don't forget about php max_execution_time & memory_limit. Increase both values to maximum.

Here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento2-data-migration-tool/

You can read more

Comment: Thanks Serge, your experience is very helpful. Will report back if I find something interesting to add in the process.